# Stateful widget not updating, after being updated in setState, how to solve this?

Tags: flutter, state

I am new to Flutter. I am trying to build a Quiz App. Now, I am on the Quiz Screen, and then a quiz has multiple questions. I am showing the question title along with the answers, and when someone clicks on the answer, I am updating the `QuestionView` again with the new question data. These are stateful widgets, and when the result is fetched I am using `setState` to update the widget, and if I place a break point there I can see that the things are updated, but that is not rendered on the screen or the view is not changed, it has same title, answers and everything. I am using an `optionTap` method and you can find it in the comments below. I have mentioned where I am tapping the option and what is done below it.

Here's what I have done so far:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_app/Constants/constants.dart';
import 'package:flutter_app/Models/question_model.dart';
import 'package:flutter_app/ViewModels/QuestionsVM.dart';
import 'package:font_awesome_flutter/font_awesome_flutter.dart';

QuizQuestionViewModel questionViewModel = QuizQuestionViewModel();

QuizQuestionModel _questionModel;
Widget updateWidget;

class SQQuiz extends StatefulWidget {
  final QuizQuestionModel quizQuestionModel;
  final int quizId;

  SQQuiz({Key key, @required this.quizQuestionModel, @required this.quizId})
      : super(key: key);
  @override
  _SQQuizState createState() =>
      _SQQuizState(quizQuestionModel: quizQuestionModel, quizId: quizId);
}

class _SQQuizState extends State<SQQuiz> {
  final QuizQuestionModel quizQuestionModel;
  final int quizId;

  _SQQuizState(
      {Key key, @required this.quizQuestionModel, @required this.quizId});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    _questionModel = quizQuestionModel;
    updateWidget = QuestionView(
      quizQuestionModel: _questionModel,
      quizId: quizId,
    );
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        leading: Container(
          child: Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              IconButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.pop(context);
                },
                icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        title: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 0),
          child: Container(
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget>[
                Text(
                  _questionModel.questionDetail.quizName,
                  style: TextStyle(color: Constants.greyColor, fontSize: 12),
                  textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  width: 14,
                ),
                CircularProgressIndicator(
                  value: 15,
                  strokeWidth: 2,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
        actions: <Widget>[
          Container(
            margin: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 10),
            child: Center(
              child: Container(
                child: Text("SCORE ${_questionModel.score}"),
              ),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
      body: SafeArea(child: updateWidget),
    );
  }
}

class QuestionView extends StatefulWidget {
  final QuizQuestionModel quizQuestionModel;
  final int quizId;

  QuestionView(
      {Key key, @required this.quizQuestionModel, @required this.quizId})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  _QuestionViewState createState() => _QuestionViewState(
        quizQuestionModel: quizQuestionModel,
        quizId: quizId,
      );
}

class _QuestionViewState extends State<QuestionView> {
  final QuizQuestionModel quizQuestionModel;
  final int quizId;

  _QuestionViewState({@required this.quizQuestionModel, @required this.quizId});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    QuestionDetail questionDetail = quizQuestionModel.questionDetail;

    return Column(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      children: <Widget>[
        Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: <Widget>[
            SizedBox(
              height: 10,
            ),
            Text(
              "Question ${quizQuestionModel.count}/${quizQuestionModel.totalCount}",
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 5,
            ),
            Image(
              image: NetworkImage(
                questionDetail.pic,
              ),
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
            ),
            Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10, horizontal: 50),
              color: Constants.orangeColor,
              child: Text(
                questionDetail.title,
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontSize: 16,
                ),
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              ),
            ),
            ListView.builder(
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                Answers answers = questionDetail.answers[index];
                return Card(
                  elevation: 5,
                  margin:
                      const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10, horizontal: 0),
                  child: ListTile(
                    onTap: () { //This is where I am tapping the option
                      optionTap(
                        context: context,
                        sessionId: quizQuestionModel.sessionId,
                        quizId: quizId,
                        questionId: questionDetail.questionId,
                        answerId: answers.id,
                        hintUsed: false,
                        fiftyUsed: false,
                      ).then((response) {
                        setState(() { //Here the updateWidget is updated, which you can see in the body, but it is not rendered
                          _questionModel = response;
                          updateWidget = new QuestionView(
                            quizQuestionModel: response,
                            quizId: quizId,
                          ); // The new QuestionView with new details
                        });
                      });
                    },
                    contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10),
                    title: Text(
                      answers.title,
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              },
              itemCount: questionDetail.answers.length,
              physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
              shrinkWrap: true,
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 20,
            ),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              children: <Widget>[
                RaisedButton(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 50),
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {
                    print("50-50 Tapped");
                  },
                  child: Text(
                    "50 | 50\n ${quizQuestionModel.fiftyCoin} coins",
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Wrap(
                  spacing: 3,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.coins),
                    Text("${quizQuestionModel.coins}"),
                  ],
                ),
                RaisedButton(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 50),
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {
                    print("Hint Tapped");
                  },
                  child: Text(
                    "HINT\n ${quizQuestionModel.hintUsed} coins",
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ],
        )
      ],
    );
  }
```

There are no errors at the moment, can anyone please help me with this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

No offence - but I think you have completely misunderstood the concept of state management in flutter.

If you have a stateful widget, the setState() method triggers the build() method again. So setState is a notifier to say: Hey there was an update to our variable, please build again.

Your Stateful Widget is doing that. BUT there are no new updates on variables from that widget, because your variables ARE OUTSIDE of the widget. They won't get updated for your StatefulWidget. Consider to rethink you architecture. For small Apps it is enough to pass the variables in a constructor.

Here are some links to get closer to the Flutter-State-Management-Concept:

https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/codelab

https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/options